# Vue: Load static script

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I feel like this should be a very trivial thing to accomplish, yet I've been struggling for too long now. I'm trying to load a static minified script in my vue project.

This is my project structure:

```
project
--  public
        index.html
--  src
        App.vue
        main.js
    --  static
            p5.min.js
            vanta.waves.min.js
```

I'm trying to follow the setup as instructed [here](https://github.com/tengbao/vanta):

```
<script src="three.r92.min.js"></script>
<script src="vanta.waves.min.js"></script>
<script>
  VANTA.WAVES('#my-background')
</script>
```

Since I'm only using the script in one component, I would like to load it there instead of globally including it in the `index.html` file.

```
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    animate() {
      const p5Script = document.createElement('script')
      p5Script.async = true;
      p5Script.defer = true;
      p5Script.id = 'p5'
      p5Script.src = '@/static/p5.min.js';
      document.head.appendChild(p5Script);

      const vantaScript = document.createElement('script')
      vantaScript.async = true;
      vantaScript.defer = true;
      vantaScript.id = 'vanta'
      vantaScript.src = '@/static/vanta.topology.min.js'
      document.head.appendChild(vantaScript);
      vantaScript.onload = () => {
        // window???
        window.VANTA.TOPOLOGY({
          el: '#vanta',
          color: 0xced4b1,
          backgroundColor: 0xe0ebeb
        })
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.animate();
  },
});
```

I'm trying to access the VANTA object on window after it loads, but there is none. It feels like my approach is just wrong to begin with, but I'm not able to find any documentation on how to include static scripts?

Comment: Try `created` instead of `mounted`

Comment: Also check the path `@/static/p5.min.js` should be `/static/p5.min.js` or whatever path it is on your server

Comment: @nomadoda, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @krry Sorry, unfortunately I did not.

Comment: @nomadoda, I ended up loading the scripts from `public/index.html` which worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Check this repo for a vue vanta component with slots to use in specific components https://github.com/iwatakeshi/vue-vanta